# How to capture NEAR samart contract logs (env::log)?

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I would like to capture logs (`env::log`) in NEAR Rust smart contract tests runtime (not a terminal) and inspect the output (in a test function). How can I do it?

Comment: It's been a little while, but I don't think so, however here's a couple thoughts:
1. remember to add the silly extra flags when running tests so the tests don't "capture" the output `cargo test -- --nocapture`
2. You can `println!` inside unit tests and they'll definitely show up (if you use the flags from above)
3. If this is something deeper where you really need to see the `env::log`s, I think unit tests are not the best approach and you'll want to use simulation tests. https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/developer/contracts/test-contracts#simulation-tests

Comment: Thanks, I'm updating the text. I want to capture this in a test runtime, not in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not shipped yet. Here is the PR that will introduce it to the `near_sdk` https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/pull/229. Maybe you can just grab the code that does it, assuming it provides enough visibility.

```rust
/// Returns a copy of logs from VMLogic. Only available in unit tests.
pub fn get_logs() -> Vec<String> {
    let blockchain_interface =
        env::take_blockchain_interface().expect("Blockchain interface is not set");
    let logs = blockchain_interface
        .as_mocked_blockchain()
        .expect("MockedBlockchain interface expected")
        .logs();
    env::set_blockchain_interface(blockchain_interface);
    logs
}
```